# Closing wxpython application hangs gui

Tags: python, ssh, while-loop, quit, wx.textctrl

I this application which has a long running task via ssh, which gets the `stdout` then prints this to a `wx.TextCtrl`, all this works fine. The problem I have is being able to quit the application, currently when I do the gui hangs. The long sunning ssh task should keep running on the remote server and I just want to close the application. How can I correctly break the `while True` loop and also the ssh task when pressing the Quit button?

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys
import spur
import threading
import select
import codecs
import os
import time
import io

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        self.running_log = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(5, 5), size=(570,390))

        self.buttonGo = wx.Button(self, -1, "Go", pos=(180,420))
        self.buttonGo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Go)
        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit", pos=(285,420))
        self.buttonClose.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
        self.Show() 

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu = wx.Menu()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.sshLog1 = sshLog(self)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def Go(self, event):
        threading.Thread(target=self.sshLog1.runCommand).start()        
        threading.Thread(target=self.sshLog1.readlog1).start()

    def OnClose(self, e):
        sys.exit()
        CloseApp()

class sshLog(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = self

    def runCommand(self):
        self.output_file = io.BytesIO()
        shell = spur.SshShell(hostname='10.0.1.1', username='remoteUsername', password='remotePassword', missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
        process = shell.spawn(['ping', 'google.com', '-t'], stdout=self.output_file)
        process.wait_for_result()

    def readlog1(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            wx.CallAfter(self.readlog2)

    def readlog2(self):
        last_line = str(self.output_file.getvalue())
        wx.CallAfter(self.parent.running_log.AppendText, last_line)

###############################
########## CLOSE APP ##########
###############################
class CloseApp(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(e):
        sys.exit(0)

app = wx.App()
MainWindow(None, -1, 'My App')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted to me on the wxPython-users group:

You can’t break a “while True” loop.  You have to provide a way for the loop to exit:
        while self.LoopContinue:
Then, when you want the thread to die, you set self.sshLog1.LoopContinue to false.

However, that won’t end the other thread, which is blocking in “process.wait_for_result()”.  If you want that to be interruptible, you would have to change that into a loop as well.  However, since you don’t really DO anything after the process exits, why do you wait for it to exit at all?  Just spawn the process and return immediately.

— 
Tim Roberts, ti...@probo.com
Providenza & Boekelheide, Inc.